# Custom UITableViewCell prepareForReuse not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My `prepareForReuse` isn't working properly. I have a `UITableView` that is supposed to have a `login` `UIButton` in the first row of the first section of the table only. But when, in `prepareForReuse`, I remove the `login` button, it stays and comes onto the next batch of rows. (video to illustrate -> http://pixori.al/8g3v )

Here's my custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
#import "MAGradeCell.h"

@implementation MAGradeCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self; }

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews]; }

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    self.loginButton = nil;
    [self removeFromSuperview];
    [self.loginButton removeFromSuperview];
    self.textLabel.text = nil;

    [super prepareForReuse]; }

/*
 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated  {  [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];    // Configure the view for the selected state  }*/

@end
```

and the part of my viewcontroller that sets the cells up (`cellForRowAtIndexPath`). ie where I put the `QBFlatButton` and everything:

```
- (MAGradeCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    MAGradeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


//    // Redefine layout variables in method from `viewDidLoad`
    CGFloat inset = 20; // For padding


    if (! cell) {
        cell = [[MAGradeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }


    // Sets up attributes of each cell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.2];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    QBFlatButton* loginButton = nil;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [self configureHeaderCell:cell title:@"Grades"];

                UIView *cellView = cell.contentView;
                loginButton = [[QBFlatButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((cellView.frame.size.width - (80 + inset)), 18, 80, (cellView.frame.size.height -(cellView.frame.size.height/2)))];
                [loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonWasPressed)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                loginButton.faceColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                loginButton.sideColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                loginButton.radius = 6.0;
                loginButton.margin = 4.0;
                loginButton.depth = 3.0;
                loginButton.alpha = 0.3;

                loginButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20];
                [loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cellView addSubview:loginButton];
        } else {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
            MAGradeClient *grade = [[MAGradeClient alloc] init];
            [self configureGradesCell:cell grade:grade];
        }
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [self configureHeaderCell:cell title:@"Hourly Forecast"];
        }
        else {
            // Get hourly weather and configure using method
            MACondition *weather = [MAManager sharedManager].hourlyForecast[indexPath.row - 1];
            [self configureHourlyCell:cell weather:weather];
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [self configureHeaderCell:cell title:@"Daily Forecast"];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            // Get daily weather and configure using method
            MACondition *weather = [MAManager sharedManager].dailyForecast[indexPath.row - 1];
            [self configureDailyCell:cell weather:weather];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do:

```
self.loginButton = nil;
```

and then try to do:

```
[self.loginButton removeFromSuperview];
```

it won't work because you already nilled the reference.

Consider using a different cell identifier for this cell as it isn't really a pure reuse if you are adding and removing a button. Consider also just hiding / showing the button. If you want to remove it then change the code to:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [self.loginButton removeFromSuperview];
    self.loginButton = nil;

    self.textLabel.text = nil;

    [super prepareForReuse];
}
```

It also looks like you aren't ever setting:

```
cell.loginButton = loginButton;
```

so the cell may not have a reference to use anyway...

Comment: I flipped the two, removing before nilling, with no change.

Comment: Would I put the `cell.loginButton = loginButton` in the custom class or the view controller? I don't totally understand its purpose

Comment: In the view controller. If the view controller doesn't give the cell a reference to the button that it adds then the cell can't use it later. So, just after `[cellView addSubview:loginButton];`.

Comment: It's *almost* perfect. As in it works as long as the rows are loaded. So this problem is gone. Thanks.
The thing I think is wrong with the button now is how I've defined it in CGRectMake

Comment: you are setting content on `prepareForReuse` this is what Apple says about `prepareForReuse` usage: *For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass implementation.*