# UITableView cell displaying wrong content after height change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath, heightforrowatindexpath

I'm working on implementing a UITableView with three sections. The last row of the second section is supposed to display an instance of a UIPicker.

As such, I've changed the height for this particular row, as shown below:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat rowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight;
    if (indexPath.section == RedZoneSection && indexPath.row == MonitorConfigRow){
        rowHeight = 162;
        return rowHeight;
    }
    return rowHeight;
}
```

However, when I add that code, the first row ("Only Alert From") in the third section is adding a UISwitch to it's view which should not be there, as shown below:

[image]

Below is where I implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the third section:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForTimeOfDayRestrictionsRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SettingsRowCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.922 green:0.937 blue:0.949 alpha:1];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case HourTimeZoneRow:
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Only Alert From", @"Only Alert Row");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT** The specific UISwitch that is being shown again in the incorrect place is originally in the second cell in the first section of my table. Below is the implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for that section:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForSubscribedNotificationsRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SettingsRowCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.922 green:0.937 blue:0.949 alpha:1];

    UISwitch *cellSwitch = nil;

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case RowOne:
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Row One", @"Row One");
            cellSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
            cell.accessoryView = cellSwitch;
            break;

        case RowTwo:
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Row Two", @"Row Two");
                cell.accessoryView = cellSwitch;
                break;
 //            cell.textLabel.text = nil ;
            cell.accessoryView = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            accessoryViewIsShowing = FALSE;
            break;
    }
    if (cell.accessoryView == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Cell accessoryView is nil");
    }
    else if (cell.accessoryView != nil){
        NSLog(@"Cell accessoryView is not nil");
    }

    NSLog(@"Section: %ld, Row: %ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);

    return cell;
}
```

Does anyone know why changing the height of a specific cell with cause incorrect content to be displayed in a cell in another section?

Comment: I cannot find the part where you add `UISwitch` programmatically to table cells. Is there additional code in your `cellForTimeOfDayRestrictionsRowAtIndexPath:` that you did not show to shorten the example?

Comment: HI @dasblinkenlight, Yes, I was afraid of the question being too long. I just edited it to include where the 'UISwitch' is being added to the cells in the first row. Thank you!

Comment: You are recycling a cell and failing to remove the switch from the old cell.

Comment: @HotLicks, where should I remove the switch from the old cell?

Comment: Either implement a subclass of UITableViewCell and use `prepareForReuse`, or put "cleanup" logic in `cellForRow...` which kicks in if a cell recycled.

Comment: Of course, another option is to use different cell identifiers for the different cell "styles" you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is there because of an error related to recycling cells in the `tableView:cellForSubscribedNotificationsRowAtIndexPath:` method. Changing the height of one of the cells makes this error visible.

You need to add code to the `default` case to remove accessories and cell text that you add for `RowOne` and `RowTwo`:

```
default:
    cell.textLabel.text = nil;
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
    break;
```

Otherwise, a "recycled" cell in rows other than `RowOne` and `RowTwo`, which used to be `RowOne` or `RowTwo`, would contain the old text and accessory view that was there before the cell has been recycled.

Another alternative to solving this would be [overriding `prepareForReuse`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22607293/335858).

Comment: That reasoning does make sense. I did try your suggestion, however; I'm still getting the exact same behavior :/

Comment: @narner That's strange - there's something else in the logic of the method that keeps an old accessory view there. I would add a call to `NSLog` before returning cell to see two things: the row number, and a true/false that indicates if cell's accessory view is `nil`.

Comment: I did try that, and got the following output: Section: 0, Row: 0, Accessory view is showing, Section: 0, Row: 1,  Accessory view is not showing, Section: 0, Row: 0, Accessory view is not showing, Section: 0, Row: 1, Accessory view is not showing

Comment: @narner That's very strange. I would also try setting `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;` but I am not sure if it is going to change anything: if your debug code says that the accessory view is `nil`, yet it is showing up, it looks like a Cocoa touch bug.

Comment: I tried setting `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;`, but still had the same effect. I added my debugging code to my question, would you mind taking a look to see if I should check for anything else?

Comment: @narner can you replace `if (accessoryViewIsShowing)` check with `if (cell.accessoryView != nil)` check? Because otherwise you are not double-checking the result of the logic above.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This time, the check showed that the accessoryView is not nil four times.

Comment: @narner That's a good start - now you know that something in the logic of your code does things differently from how you think it should do it. You can trace your logic back to discover the wrong code path, or take a "shotgun approach" and `nil` out the accessory view at the same place where you set cell's background.